# Can you set the model start time after exporting the model as an application

Tags: anylogic

Since I would like to let other people use my model (not on cloud), I export it as an application, so would it be possible to set the model start date on the simulation page before running the model? As we can see in the picture, I can only set "running until date" of the model instead of the "running from date" on the simulation page. Thanks in advance! [Simulation Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kFNX.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To control the start time, you need to generate the following code in your experiment on the initial experiment setup:

```
getEngine().setStartTime(50); //assuming you want to start after 50 time units
```

also you can use getEngine().setStartDate method if you want to select a starting date

but i think you can't have that value as a parameter in your user interface because the start time is set before your user interface shows up... you would need another pre-userinterface where you set it up and runs the anylogic exported file separately by interacting with some database where the start time value is stored...

But maybe there's another way? I don't know.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I tried getEngine().setStartDate() on the simulation page before running the model, and it totally works!